# What is the maximum size of the area in which HTML content can be rendered in the Google Hangout App?

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

I building a lot of HTML content in my Google Hangout application and I would like the know the maximum and recommended size in pixels that my HTML content should take, since using percentages implicitly considers the People/Apps bar at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jonathan Beri](https://plus.google.com/108249232416813189685), one of the developer support people for the Google+ API, has posted these UI suggestions:
http://blog.jonathanberi.com/2012/07/designing-for-hangout-apps-dimensions.html

Comment: I would add that there is really no maximum size on the iFrame. My recommendation to most people is to design for a 13" Macbook Air (mine is 1440x900) and be responsive as it scales. That way, your app will still look great on a 30" monitor.